# Python3 - redirected stderr not reset properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout, stderr

I have written function that could capture `stdout` and `stderr` into string when executing some other function. It seemed to work at first, but there is a problem with stderr not being reset properly.

It captures stderr first time, but second time, it tries to use closed string buffer, when I expect it to use new buffer.

Here is my code:

```
import io
import sys
import contextlib
from typing import Optional
import logging

def capture_output(
    target: object,
    args: Optional[tuple] = None,
        kwargs: Optional[dict] = None) -> str:
    """Redirect stdout and stderr into string buffer and capture it.

    target object is executed with optional args, kwargs and all stdout/
    stderr that is captured, returned in string form.

    Args:
        target: object to execute, usually a function.
        args: target positional arguments (default: {None})
        kwargs: target keyword arguments (default: {None})
    """
    if not args:
        args = ()
    if not kwargs:
        kwargs = {}
    # with _setup_capture_output() as sio:
    with io.StringIO() as sio:
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(sio), contextlib.redirect_stderr(sio):
            target(*args, **kwargs)
            output = sio.getvalue()

    print(output)


def dummy():
    print('dummy test')
    logging.warning('dummy test')

def dummy2():
    print('dummy2 test')


capture_output(dummy)  # works
capture_output(dummy)  # won't work anymore.

capture_output(dummy2)  # works
capture_output(dummy2)  # works
```

Running `capture_output` second time (if stderr needs to be captured, as in `logging.warning` case), it errors out:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 982, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

P.S. if I try to catch only stdout (print), then it does not explode on any number of `capture_output` calls.

Comment: Evidently the `logging` module caches the stderr file object at the first `logging.warning` call. Why or where it does that though, I have no idea. Probably deserves a bug report.

Comment: For anyone wanting a solution to this, it was raised as a bug report (as per previous commenter's suggestion) here: https://bugs.python.org/issue36193. It was ultimately closed as "not a bug". I struggle to follow the details at this point, but the suggested solution, roughly speaking, was to explicitly handle the issue with `logging` with one approach being the example here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-a-context-manager-for-selective-logging

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem still exists even if a handler is explicitly set. I wrapped all the details into an issue mentioned above.

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/80374

Update: In this case when loggers are used. It is the problem of setting handlers of the root logger in the redirected context and all other logger will refer to those handlers as they are children of the root logger.

Some potential solutions are:

- Set `_LOGGER_1.propagate = False` (the example child logger in this case)
- Reconfigure the root logger like this

```
   def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
       self.redirect_stdout.close()
       self.redirect_stderr.close()
       sys.stdout = self.original_stdout
       sys.stderr = self.original_stderr
       # restore any logging handler that lead to redirect_io_obj
       all_loggers = [logging.getLogger("")] + [j for i, j in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.items()]
       for logger in all_loggers:
           if hasattr(logger, "handlers"):
               for handler in logger.handlers:
                   if hasattr(handler, "stream"):
                       if handler.stream is self.redirect_stdout:
                           handler.stream = self.original_stdout
                       if handler.stream is self.redirect_stderr:
                           handler.stream = self.original_stderr
```